# Trouble updating a url in a rich text field

Tags: lotusscript

I have a bunch of urls/hotspots pointing to files for download.  I  have to replace a url domain from 'www.company.com' to 'xyz.company.com'.  I wrote the following agent to do this:

```
doc.DT2Build_File_bu = doc.DT2Build_File
Set rtfld = doc.Getfirstitem("DT2Build_File")
Set RTRange = rtfld.Createrange()
numReplaced = RTRange.Findandreplace("www.company.com", "xyz.company.com", 16)
Call doc.save(True, False)
```

This works in that the domain is properly updated but I found that often (tho, not always), the hotspot is changed.  So instead of the rest of the url (containing the location and filename) is no longer a hotspot -- the only part that's a hotspot is now just the domain -- the part I replaced with this code.  Is there another way to do this that preserves the entire hotspot?
Thank
Clem